# как добавить DataTable row с Array, если первый идет bool column?

Tags: c#, массивы, datatable

Есть готовый аррей который нужно закинуть в каждую строку.
Но если добавить первым bool который должен быть обязательно фалсом...

то не выйдет сделать вот так:

```
 dataTable.Rows.Add(false, otherCells );
```

где otherCells  -- массив с остальными ячейками дата тейбла...
А как сделать подобное правильно:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, имеются таблица и массив:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnA", typeof(bool));
dataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnB", typeof(int));
dataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnC", typeof(int));

var otherCells = new object[] { 1, 2 };
```

---

Простейший способ в лоб:

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(false, otherCells[0], otherCells[1]);
```

Более семантичный пример:

```
var row = dataTable.NewRow();
row["Column1"] = false;
row["Column2"] = otherCells[0];
row["Column3"] = otherCells[1];
dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

Если колонок в таблице и, соответственно, элементов в массиве много, то, чтобы не перечислять их вручную, можно делать так:

```
var list = otherCells.ToList();
list.Insert(0, false);
dataTable.Rows.Add(list.ToArray());
```